# The conditions on a Topological group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

I am familiar with group theory and topology. Now I am studying the concept of  topological group. As per [Munkres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group), it is defined as follows:

Let $G$ be a group together with a topology $\textit{T}$ defined on it. Then the topological space $(G,T)$ is said to be a topological group, if the following two functions

1. $G \times G \to G$, $(x,y) \mapsto xy$,
2. $G \to G$, $x \mapsto x^{−1}$

are continuous.

I can understand that the first condition gives a relationship between the binary operation defined on $G$ and the topology $T$. But I couldn't get why the second condition is necessary ? What will happen if we exclude the second condition ?

Comment: The second property also relates topolgical structure to group structure, note that $\cdot^{-1}$ is a purely algebraic construct. This is analogous to how you define a subgroup: it is a subset $H$ such that if $g,h\in H$ then $gh\in H$, and if $g\in H$ then $g^{-1}\in H$. Without that second assumption you get that $\mathbb{N}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, which we know is not. And without this stronger assumption (on topological groups) many theorems just don't work. Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratopological_group

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this.